# Distribution/Variance of correlated squared normal random variables

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, variance, covariance, correlation

If $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots, X_{N}$ are identically distributed normal random variables with mean $0$ and variance $\frac{(N+3)D\sigma^{2}}{N}$, then I want to calculate the distribution, or at least the variance of $Z = X_{1}^{2} + X_{2}^{2} + \ldots + X_{N}^{2}$.

I already found that $Cov(X_{i}, X_{j}) = \frac{\sigma^{2}D}{N}$, $\forall i,j \in \{1, 2, \ldots, N\}$ and that $E[X_{i}^{2}] = \frac{(N+3)D\sigma^{2}}{N}$, $Var(X_{i}^{2}) = \frac{(N+3)^{2}{D^{2}\sigma}^{4}}{N^{2}}$, $\forall i,j \in \{1, 2, \ldots, N\}$.

My problem is that they are correlated and I do not know how to compute the variance and the distribution of $Z$.

Any help would be highly considered!

Comment: Rotate to new coordinates which are uncorrelated.

Comment: Thanks! How do I do that?

Comment: Your covariance matrix is a multiple of the diagonal matrix plus a rank 1 matrix, so it has  $(N-1)$ eigenvalues that are equal plus one more, corresponding to the eigenvector of all $1$s. From which you can deduce that $Z$ is the sum of a multiple of a degree-of-freedom $N-1$ chi squared rv plus a different multiple of a degree-of-freedom $1$ chi square.